# Tooltip, accessibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

Building a nice accessible web page is hard. Currently, Im trying to make a tooltip web accessible and I need help. Do you guys have any piece of advice for it? Like what *aria* attributes  I should use. Or some other important thing you want to add!

Moreover, How do I prevent the screen reader from reading the tooltip, if it hasnt been shown? My approach here is to make it using javascript,  adding and deleting `aria-hidden` attribute, but I want to avoid JS as much as possible.

Comment: Did you look into role="tooltip"

Comment: Can you add what exactly you want the tooltips to appear on? Can you post a code sample? (Is this just static HTML or a web application?)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to show the tooltip on a focusable element (if this element is not focusable, you should set the `tabindex` attribute)

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" aria-describedby="mytooltip" />
<span id="mytooltip" role="tooltip" class="tooltip" aria-hidden="true">Tooltip for the textbox</span>
```

The `aria-describedby` will set the relationship between your focusable element and the tooltip. The `tooltip` role support is not very important, but you should use it as it's designed for this subject.

Once this is done, you just have to set the initial state in the CSS:

```
  .tooltip[aria-hidden='true'] {display: none}
  .tooltip[aria-hidden='false'] {display: block}
```

and define the `aria-hidden` attribute to true on `focus` or `mouseover` events using your favorite javascript code, and to false on `blur` and `mouseout` events.

Comment: This could be done way simpler by using the `hidden` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The above example is working fine. we can achieve the same by using below jQuery code.

```js
<script>
        $("#test").tooltip();
</script>
```

```
<a id="test" href="#" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
```

But another issue is the screen reader will not read the tooltip on mouseover.

By using jquery-ui version 1.12, the screen reader can read the tooltip on mouseover, but the problem is it can't identify the role and name of the tooltip container element.
So is there any way to achieve that functionality?